# DevExpress ChartControl with scrollbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, charts, devexpress

I'd like to had Multiple Chart to a chart control. But if I have 1 chart it takes the whole chart control, on the other side if I have 15 charts, the chart control is telling me to increase the size to view the charts.

I'd like to have every chart all the same height, no matter how many chart I have and be able to scroll down to view more chart.

[image: When I have a lot of Charts]
[image: when I have too many charts]
[image: When I have only 1 charts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question.

You can use the [XtraScrollableControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsXtraScrollableControltopic). Simply place it on your form and then place the charts into the control.

[image]

You should make your charts the size you want them to be and the scroller does the rest :)

Comment: So I don't have to use ChartControl? only XtraScrollable?

Comment: You should use the XtraScrollableControl and then place the chart control in it.

Comment: Just tried it, and it seems to not working. I have set my Scrollable to `DockStyle.Fill` and the ChatControl inside is set to `DockStyle.None` and in my code I do `this.chartControl.Size = new Size(this.chartControl.Width, this.chartControl.Height + 200);` for every Chart i'm adding. What am I missing?

Comment: @PLAudet It works for me. Can I suggest you try what i wrote in the answer? If you can get the basic to work you can work up from there.

Comment: @PLAudet Then I'd tell you to ask the Devex team cause I tried it in 3 different ways and it works. There you can upload a project and they can check what's going wrong. I haven't a clue why it's not working for you.

Comment: @PLAudet btw is it intentional that when deciding the size of the chart you use the size of the chart and not of the scrollable control?

Comment: Yep, what i'm trying to do is to increase the chartControl size by 200px each time I add a chart. I forgot to tell you that, `this.chartControl.Size = new Size(this.chartControl.Width, this.chartControl.Height + 200);` is in a for loop

Comment: @PLAudet Can you edit the original post and add all your code?

Comment: It won't be necessary, just found out that someone inserted `this.chartControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill'` somewhere in the code. Thanks for your help.